# Custom Attachment Type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, media-library

I want to create a "photography" custom post type which uses attachment's same edit/upload panel. Exact same panels usage for "attachment" post type but with "photography" name. Is it possible?

Comment: You can just change the name of attachment? is that good enough?

Comment: Sadly no :< I need media library too. You can think it as somehow special media library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems its impossible with WordPress 3.5 at the moment. I opened an idea for it:
http://wordpress.org/extend/ideas/topic/custom-attachment-type
Support if you like idea please.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding Additional Fields**

```
function add_image_attachment_fields_to_edit( $form_fields, $post ) {

    // Remove the "Description" field, we're not using it
    unset( $form_fields['post_content'] ); 

    // Add description text (helps) to the "Title" field
    $form_fields['post_title']['helps'] = 'Use a descriptive title for the image. This will make it easy to find the image in the future and will improve SEO.';

    // Re-order the "Caption" field by removing it and re-adding it later
    $form_fields['post_excerpt']['helps'] = 'Describe the significants of the image pertaining to the site.';
    $caption_field = $form_fields['post_excerpt'];
    unset($form_fields['post_excerpt']);

    // Re-order the "File URL" field
    $image_url_field = $form_fields['image_url'];
    unset($form_fields['image_url']);

    // Add Caption before Credit field 
    $form_fields['post_excerpt'] = $caption_field;

    // Add a Credit field
    $form_fields["credit_text"] = array(
        "label" => __("Credit"),
        "input" => "text", // this is default if "input" is omitted
        "value" => esc_attr( get_post_meta($post->ID, "_credit_text", true) ),
        "helps" => __("The owner of the image."),
    );

    // Add a Credit field
    $form_fields["credit_link"] = array(
        "label" => __("Credit URL"),
        "input" => "text", // this is default if "input" is omitted
        "value" => esc_url( get_post_meta($post->ID, "_credit_link", true) ),
        "helps" => __("Attribution link to the image source or owners website."),
    );

    // Add Caption before Credit field 
    $form_fields['image_url'] = $image_url_field;

    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "add_image_attachment_fields_to_edit", null, 2);
```

**Save The Data as Custom Fields**

```
function add_image_attachment_fields_to_save( $post, $attachment ) {
    if ( isset( $attachment['credit_text'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_credit_text', esc_attr($attachment['credit_text']) );

    if ( isset( $attachment['credit_link'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post['ID'], '_credit_link', esc_url($attachment['credit_link']) );

    return $post;
}
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", "add_image_attachment_fields_to_save", null , 2);
```

**Display Attachment Custom Fields**

```
function base_image_credit( $post_ID = null ) {
    // Get the post ID of the current post if not set
    if ( !$post_ID ) {
        global $post;
        $post_ID = $post->ID;
    }

    // Get all the attachments for the current post (object stdClass)
    $attachments = get_children('post_type=attachment&post_parent=' . $post->ID);

    // If attachments are found
    if ( isset($attachments) && !empty($attachments) ) {
        // Get the first attachment
        $first_attachment = current($attachments);
        $attachment_fields = get_post_custom( $first_attachment->ID );

        // Get custom attachment fields
        $credit_text = ( isset($attachment_fields['_credit_text'][0]) && !empty($attachment_fields['_credit_text'][0]) ) ? esc_attr($attachment_fields['_credit_text'][0]) : '';
        $credit_link = ( isset($attachment_fields['_credit_link'][0]) && !empty($attachment_fields['_credit_link'][0]) ) ? esc_url($attachment_fields['_credit_link'][0]) : '';

        // Output HTML if you want
        $credit = ( $credit_text && $credit_link ) ? "Image provided by <a href='$credit_link'>$credit_text</a>" : false;
    }

    return $credit;
}
```

**Using the display image credit function**

This function can be used anywhere in a plugin or theme. I’ve used the functionality on single.php like this

```
<?php if( function_exists('base_image_credit') ) echo base_image_credit(); ?>
```

Orginal [tutorial](http://www.kevinleary.net/add-custom-meta-fields-media-attachments-wordpress/)

Regards

Comment: how is adding custom fields make an attachment post type as "photography" custom post type?

Answer (score 0):

You can still add the codes in your theme’s functions.php file to make it work.

```
function be_attachment_field_credit( $form_fields, $post ) {
        $form_fields['be-photographer-name'] = array(
            'label' => 'Photographer Name',
            'input' => 'text',
            'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'be_photographer_name', true ),
            'helps' => 'If provided, photo credit will be displayed',
        );

        $form_fields['be-photographer-url'] = array(
            'label' => 'Photographer URL',
            'input' => 'text',
            'value' => get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'be_photographer_url', true ),
            'helps' => 'Add Photographer URL',
        );

        return $form_fields;
    }

    add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'be_attachment_field_credit', 10, 2 );

    /**
     * Save values of Photographer Name and URL in media uploader
     *
     * @param $post array, the post data for database
     * @param $attachment array, attachment fields from $_POST form
     * @return $post array, modified post data
     */

    function be_attachment_field_credit_save( $post, $attachment ) {
        if( isset( $attachment['be-photographer-name'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'be_photographer_name', $attachment['be-photographer-name'] );

        if( isset( $attachment['be-photographer-url'] ) )
    update_post_meta( $post['ID'], 'be_photographer_url', esc_url( $attachment['be-photographer-url'] ) );

        return $post;
    }

    add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_save', 'be_attachment_field_credit_save', 10, 2 );
    ?>
```

If you want to display the fields in your attachments template, then simply paste the following codes inside the loop:

```
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'be_photographer_url', true);
```

If you want to display the fields for your featured image in your archive template or any other template, then simply use:

```
echo get_post_meta(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'be_photographer_url', true);
```